# CSS - Border stretched to whole height of navbar

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am trying to make a border on the right of most of my LIs (that are also anchor tags) fill the entirety of the div vertically, with a width of 1em like this (my figma mockup):
[image: figma mockup]

However, all I am getting currently is this:
[image: what I am getting]

Here is my (S)CSS:

```css
.navbar-main {
    margin-top: 2em;
    display: flex;
    background-color: hsl(206, 97%, 13%);
    color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
    border-radius: 34px;
    width: 90vw;
    height: 3em;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    justify-content: space-between;
    text-align: center;

    .links {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        margin-left: 2em;
        align-items: center;
    }

    ul {
        display: inherit;
        flex-direction: row;
        align-items: center;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        gap: 1em;
        height: 100%;
    }

    /* Add a vertical border to the right of all of the lis that stretches to the whole of the div vertically */
    li {
        border-right: 1px solid hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
    }


    .langselect {
        margin-right: 2em;
        display: inherit;
        justify-content: flex-end;
        align-items: center;
    }

    .icon {
        margin-right: 0.5em;
        height: 1em;
        width: 1em;
        font-size: inherit;
        text-align: center;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
}
```

And here is my HTML (REACT):

```html
<div className="navbar-main">
    <div className="links">
        <ul> {/*TODO: Remember to put icons before the a tags! (USE BOOTSTRAP ICONS!) */}
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <FaHome className="home icon"/>
                    Portfolio/CV
                </a>
            </li>
            
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <FaBookOpen className="book icon"/>
                    Portfolio/CV
                </a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <FaPuzzlePiece className="puzzle icon"/>
                    !?@!#*$%
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div className="langselect">
        <FaGlobe className="world icon"/>
        <p>Language Select</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

All help is appreciated, thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you add the css of the list?

Comment: What do you mean css of the list? All the HTML (React code) and the (S)CSS has been provided for this problem, and the navbar as a whole.

Comment: can you put this code in codepen?

Comment: Sure. Will do now.

Comment: For some reason, it will not work on codepen.

Comment: In the code you shared, the only style for li is the one that tries to create the right border. But where is the `list-style: none` property, I see in the screenshot that you are using it. I mean those styles

Comment: The `list-style: none` property is in my `Globals.scss` file in the root of my SRC folder, as shown here: https://ibb.co/6mMb0fv, however that shouldn't be neccissary information to fix my certain problem - and it is so basic, I did not include it.

Answer (score -1):

Turns out after a bit of back and forth debugging and writing code, I found out that I could do this:

```css
li {
        display: inherit;
        height: 100%;
        border-right: 1px solid hsl(206, 94%, 20%);
        padding-right: 1em;


        a {
            margin-top: auto;
            margin-bottom: auto;
        }
    }

    li:last-child {
        border-right: none;
        padding-right: 0;
    }
```

This works flawlessly too, as seen here:
[image: flawlessly]

Thanks anyway for your guys' help!